# SQL join multiple Tables

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to join 3 tables into 1. But I am getting a "Could not be bound" Error message.

As I'm new to SQL,  I am not sure if its error in my code or if I have set the Table relationships up wrong?

I have a picture of my primary and foreign keys here:
http://crystalise.tw/shadow/public.php?service=files&t=b036d2b2516576b27532b947dfb96293

Here is my SQL code I play with.
 I have managed to get the first attempt using only 2 tables to work fine.  But I get problems when I try to implement the 3rd table.   What should I take a closer look on this time ?

```
--
--SELECT Artists.nameArtist, Albums.nameAlbum 
--  FROM Artists
--  INNER JOIN Albums 
--  ON Artists.idArtist = Albums.idArtist
--  ORDER BY nameAlbum 
--  



SELECT Artists.nameArtist, Albums.nameAlbum, Songs.nameSong 
  FROM Artists
  JOIN Songs
  ON Artists.idArtist = Albums.idArtist

JOIN Albums
  ON Artists.idArtist = Songs.idArtist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to order your join conditions correctly.  You cannot include a table name (or alias) in the `on` condition before it appears in the `from` clause:

```
SELECT Artists.nameArtist, Albums.nameAlbum, Songs.nameSong 
  FROM Artists
  JOIN Songs
  ON Artists.idArtist = Songs.idArtist
JOIN Albums
  ON Artists.idArtist = Albums.idArtist
```

Comment: Yes I noticed than as well

Comment: Correct answer. Want to +1 this. Please post a comment to it so that I can +1 this tomorrow as I exhausted my quota of daily votes.

Comment: @Rachcha: Actually, unless you expect to post hundreds of comments or put up a huge amount of any other kind of loggable activity in the hours to come, you've already as much as bookmarked this answer for the next day by posting your comment. You can always visit your [Activity page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1151269/rachcha?tab=activity) and, while this post exists, find your comment and jump to this post.